# In Chrome browser some videos are not playing

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, cross-browser, video-streaming

I have my java based application deployed in two environment Staging and production. My application has a video embedded on the home page.

1. I tested staging deployed application and find that embedded video working fine (playing) in IE, Firefox and Chrome browser.
2. When I tested my production deployed application I find that embedded video is playing fine on IE and Firefox but not playing in Chrome.

Same version of code is deployed on both Staging and Chrome.

Is there any security setting in production environment restrict video to run in chrome browser?

I googled lot of stuff but didn't find anything concrete.

Any pointer on how to resolve the problem is highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in Chrome?

Comment: Embedded Java application? I find it amazing you can run it in Chrome at all, the Java plugin has been effectively disabled for quite some time now.

Comment: @ Jaromanda - No error in consol.

Comment: @ Gimby - yes embedded in Java application. Where I can find chrome java plugin and how to configure to run the video?

Comment: @ManojKumar http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml